# Who or whom? How to substitute him or her for whom here?

Tags: grammar, who-whom

> 1. My brother who I'm older than him, lives in Paris.
> 2. My brother whom I'm older than[NOT than him], lives in Paris.
> 3. My brother who's younger than me lives in Paris.

Why should we ommit "him" after "than" in the second example? Is this necessary?

How can we use [this recommended trick](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/83/311104) here, for the example number 2?

How to substitute him for whom? How to rearrange the word order here?

Are the first and third examples the same? (in terms of meaning)
Are they true?

Answer (score 1):

1. The 'him' is redundant. It is a pronoun that is supposed to take the place of the noun referred to (your brother) but your brother is already in the sentence so does not need to be represented by a pronoun.

So "My brother, who I am older than, lives in Paris" (please note the use of commas) is grammatically OK but sounds very unnatural to a native speaker.

2.'whom' is wrong here because 'whom' must refer to the object of a verb , and your brother is not the object of the sentence but is actually the subject of the sentence:'My brother...lives in Paris'. You are describing what your brother is  - younger than you - not referring to him as the object. You could have 'whom' if the description of your brother took a different, adjectival, form. For example, you could say "My brother, wiser than whom no Frenchman can be, lives in Paris". That means the same as 'My brother, who is wiser than any Frenchman, lives in Paris'. The difference is that the descriptive clause in the first case describes Frenchmen and in the second it describes your brother.

3. is fine, but @HankyPanky's version is better.

Comment: If you have *two* brothers, one of whom you're *younger* than, then the commas should *not* be used because you need a restrictive appositive. You can't just say to not use them. In the right context, their omission is essential.

Comment: Why not: My brother, who is older than me, lives in Paris. > I think this sounds more natural, at least I often hear it back then in US. or better: My older brother lives in Paris.